# If a vector space has a countable basis, can we construct it?

Tags: vector-spaces, constructive-mathematics

Given that we cannot (?) exhibit a basis for a vector space of all real sequences (certainly that basis would be uncountable), but there is a countable basis for polynomials, i.e. $1,x,x^2,x^2,\ldots$, I would like to know,

If a vector space $V$ has a countable basis, can it be always constructed/enumerated (or whatever the correct term is)?

Comment: @EricWofsey; OP is asking if the members of the basis can be enumerated because it is countable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that there is a computable vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with no computable basis.  This also shows that we cannot prove constructively that every countable vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference/theorem name?

Comment: I am not sure that there is a perfectly accessible resource. The proof should be in Simpson's *Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic*, but phrased in a more general way.